# Extract fasta sequence flanking an amino acid

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I'm trying to come up with a python script to extract a 12-amino acid sequence flanking a given amino acid (6 on each direction) a fasta sequence.

### Input

I have 2 inputs: a fasta file and a panda data frame.

The fasta file looks like this:

```
> sp|P00001| some text here 1
MKLLILTCLVAVALARPKHPIKKVSPTFDTNMVGKHQGLPQEVLNENLLRFFVAPFPEVFGKEKVSLDAGPGMCSRNE
>sp|P00002| some text here 2
MSSGNAKIGHPAPNFKATAVMPDGQFKDISLSDYKGKYVVFFFYPLDFTFVCPTGLGRSSYRATSCLPALCLP
>sp|P00003| some text here 3
MSVLDSGNFSWKMTEACMKVKIPLVKKKSLRQNLIENGKLKEFMRTHKYNLGSKYIREAATLVSEQPLQN
```

Here is my second input, a pandas data frame (2 columns 'ProteinID' and 'Phosphopeptide')

```
ProteinID  -- Phosphopeptide
P00001   --   KVSPT*FDTNMVGK
P00001  --    SLDAGPGMCS*R
P00003   --   LDS*GNFSWKMTEACMK
```

### Goal

What I need to do is the following. For each 'Phosphopeptide', I need to find the protein (ProteinID) in the fasta file header (starts with '>'). Then I need to extract the 6 amino acids preceding and following the amino acid with the asterisk marker.

### Output

My output is a new column written to the data frame and would look like this:

```
ProteinID  -- Phosphopeptide  --   NewColumn
P00001   --   KVSPT*FDTNMVGK  --   IKKVSPTFDTNMV 
P00001   --   SLDAGPGMCS*R    --   AGPGMCSRNE
P00003   --   LDS*GNFSWKMTEACMK -- MSVLDSGNFSWK
```

Note that the latter 2 rows contain peptides at the end or the beginning of their respective proteins, thus we don't have 12 amino acids to extract in these cases.

I'm having a hard time (little programming experience) to write this program and would greatly appreciate any help (advices, tips, functions, etc).

Comment: Bit confusing, can you put like : this is input and this is the expected output. So, anybody who doesn't know protein structure could understand easily. for me everything is strings.

Comment: where is the fasta file header (starts with '>') ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that the fasta was malformed. Ok, now it is fixed. thanks

Comment: Please take a look at the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format text properly. Regarding the actual question: please show us *what you have tried* and what your *specific* problems are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that extracts the relevant substring:

```
def flank(seq, pp):
    # 1: find the position of the AA preceding the '*' marker in the
    # phosphopeptide
    marked_pos = pp.find('*') - 1
    if (marked_pos < 0):
        raise ValueError("invalid phosphopeptide string")

    # 2: find the phosphopeptide (without '*') in the sequence
    pp_pos = s.find(pp.replace('*', ''))
    if pp_pos == -1:
        raise ValueError("phosphopeptide not found in the sequence")

    # avoid a negative starting index
    start = max(0, pp_pos + marked_pos - 6)

    # 3: use slicing to produce the result
    return seq[start : pp_pos + marked_pos + 7]
```

Example:

```
seq = "MKLLILTCLVAVALARPKHPIKKVSPTFDTNMVGKHQGLPQEVLNENLLRFFVAPFPEVFGKEKVSLDAGPGMCSRNE"
pp = "KVSPT*FDTNMVGK"
print(flank(seq, pp))
```

prints:

```
IKKVSPTFDTNMV
```

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you rmartinjak and sjcipher for your help.cheers, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check this: my fasta file is name 'txt':

Snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

protein_dict = [
    ('P00001', 'KVSPT*FDTNMVGK'),
    ('P00001', 'SLDAGPGMCS*R'),
    ('P00003', 'LDS*GNFSWKMTEACMK')
    ]

protein_id = None

def prepare_structure_from_fasta(file):
    fasta_structure = dict()
    with open(file, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if '>' in line:
                protein_id = line.split('|')[1]
            else:
                if not protein_id:
                    raise Exception("Wrong fasta file structure")
                fasta_structure[protein_id] = line.strip()
    return fasta_structure


def match(pattern, string):
    matc = re.search(pattern, string)
    if matc:
        return matc.groups()[0]
    return None

fasta_struct = prepare_structure_from_fasta('txt')
final_struct = []

for pro_d in protein_dict:

    pro_id = pro_d[0]
    pep_id = pro_d[1]
    first, second = pep_id.split('*')

    if len(first) <= 6:
        f_count = 7 - len(first)
    else:
        first = first[len(first) - 7:]
        f_count = 0
    if len(second) <= 6:
        s_count = 7 - len(second)
    else:
        second = second[0:6]
        s_count = 0

    _regex = '([A-Z]{0,%d}%s%s[A-Z]{0,%d})' % (f_count,first,second,s_count)
    final_struct.append((pro_id, pep_id, match(_regex, fasta_struct[pro_id])))

for pro in final_struct:
    print pro
```

Output:

```
('P00001', 'KVSPT*FDTNMVGK', 'IKKVSPTFDTNMV')
('P00001', 'SLDAGPGMCS*R', 'AGPGMCSRNE')
('P00003', 'LDS*GNFSWKMTEACMK', 'MSVLDSGNFSWK')
```